# ¿Tiene el significado "claim, allege" la palabra "pretender"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

Estoy confundido sobre el significado de la palabra "pretender". [RAE tira](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U86gASi):

> 1. tr. Querer ser o conseguir algo.
> 2. tr. Hacer diligencias para conseguir algo.
> 3. tr. Dicho de una persona: Cortejar a otra.

Los que me parecen no tienen el significado "claim, allege" en inglés.

Sin embargo, en varios diccionarios inglés-castellano, "pretender" se encuentra como una traducción por la palabra "claim".

¿Se puede usar para significar "claim" o no? ¿Si no, cuál sería la palabra más apropiada como la traducción castellana? ¿Quizás "alegar"?

Comment: Mark Twain's book "The American Claimant" has as its Spanish title "El Pretendiente Americano"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es cierto que en algunos sitios como el Wikcionario, la palabra *[pretender](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pretender#Spanish)* se traduce como *claim, allege*, pero no da ningún ejemplo de uso que apoye esa afirmación (al contrario que para otras traducciones). A mí no me suena que tengan el mismo significado. Observemos la definición que da el Cambridge Dictionary para ***[claim](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/claim)***:

1. Decir que algo es cierto o es un hecho, aunque no se pueda probar y exista la posibilidad de que no te crean. *He claims to have met the president, but I don't believe him.* En este caso la traducción sería ***afirmar***: *Afirma haber conocido al presidente, pero no le creo.* También valdría ***asegurar***.
2. Solicitar algo de valor porque crees que te pertenece o tienes un derecho sobre ello. *When King Richard III died, Henry VII claimed the English throne.* En este caso la traducción sería ***reclamar***: Cuando el rey Ricardo III murió, Enrique VII reclamó el trono de Inglaterra.*
3. Presentar una demanda escrita solicitando dinero a un gobierno u organización porque crees que tienes derecho a ello. En este caso también sería *reclamar*.

Ahora veamos las definiciones de *[allege](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/allege)*:

1. Decir que alguien ha hecho algo ilegal o equivocado sin tener pruebas que lo demuestren. *The two men allege (that) the police forced them to make false confessions.* En este caso se podría traducir por ***acusar***: *Los dos acusaron a la policía de haberles forzado a realizar falsas declaraciones.*

Se podría interpretar que la segunda acepción de *pretender* (hacer diligencias para conseguir algo) podría ser un caso genérico de la tercera acepción de *claim*, y tal vez por ahí se pudiera encontrar alguna similitud. Tal vez así:

> -- ¿Qué pretendes rellenando tanto formulario?
>
> -- Pretendo que nos devuelvan el dinero del viaje que nos cancelaron.

Pero yo esto lo traduciría como *I pretend to claim my money back*. Es decir, *pretender* sería el verbo que indica que tienes el propósito de conseguir algo, pero ese "algo" sería la reclamación ("claim"), por lo que no veo una traducción directa desde *pretender* hasta *claim* sin pasar por un paso intermedio que consistiría en añadir un segundo verbo a la expresión (*pretender reclamar*).

Nota: hablo desde mi punto de vista de hablante de español europeo, tal vez algún hablante de español de América Latina pueda aportar alguna opinión diferente.

Comment: Gracias. También puede tener el primer significado de "claim" la palabra "alegar"? O se usa para algo diferente?

Comment: @JIXiang la palabra _[alegar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1gsPDDb)_ tiene una connotación de que lo que se afirma se hace como prueba a favor de la argumentación de una persona. En cambio _claim_ carece de esa connotación, es una afirmación sin pruebas. De hecho he procurado no traducir _allege_ por _alegar_ por eso mismo.

Answer (score 1):

*pretender* es *aspirar* a algo.

> **Pretendo** ir a la fiesta. (Mi aspiración es ir a la fiesta, pero no sé si podré cumplirlo.)

Pero *claim* es más directo, con ello afirmas que algo es cierto.

> **Clamamos** que el agua ebulle a los 99 grados celsius.

Comment: Uh... Creo que "clamar" significa "exigir" o "quejarse"? No es lo mismo como "claim" en inglés?

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría el verbo "sostener" o "afirmar" para "claim". Sostienes que... O alguien afirma que... Pero no tiene por qué ser así.

Comment: Hola Juanga. Gracias por tu respuesta. Sin embargo, nótese que publicaciones tan cortas y sin referencias no son recomendables. Intenta darle mejor formato, incluir referencias a artículos relacionados de interés, poner ejemplos, etc. para que resulta de mayor ayuda. Puedes leer [answer] para tener una visión más clara. Gracias : )